# jQuery load issue. Don't know how to approach this AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

```
$("[littleBox]").load("ajax.php?eid="+$(this).attr("littlebox"));
```

the `$(this).attr("little box")` portion of the code returns `undefined`.
I'm trying to get the individual attribute of the initial `$("[littleBox]")`.

this particular line of code is called as the soon as the document is ready.

when I put predefined values, such as

```
$("[littleBox]").load("ajax.php?eid=1");
```

It works as expected. Unfortunately, I need it to load specific content based on that element's attribute. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: it happens in the `$(document).ready(function(){});` call. The ? is for the parameters of the url ajax call.

Comment: so as soon as the document is ready.

Comment: are you wraping $(document).ready(function(){ ???

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I didn't mention that but it is within that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all items with proper `this`:

```
$("[littleBox]").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    $this.load("ajax.php?eid="+ $this.attr("littlebox"));
});
```

Comment: My friend, I was dwelling on this for hours, I don't like blowing these forums up but I couldn't for the life of me figure it out. Thank you sooooo much man. Thank you everyone for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 1):

`this` **will not** refer to `$("[littleBox]")` in that context, you'll have to repeat the selector - or select the element already and re-use it:

```
var $box = $("[littleBox]");
$box.load("ajax.php?eid=" + $box.attr("littlebox"));
```

Comment: I tried the example you provide. I have more than one `$("[littleBox]")`. It appears that the variable was set to the first instance of that element, and only used the `.attr()` value of the first instance (I hope I worded that right).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review my question! I appreciate your selflessness. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. jgauffin was pretty enlightened to guess there was several elements with this attribute, was not that obvious from your question. Glad it was resolved though.

Answer (score 1):

post yout html that cotnain attr "little box" in it.
is it like

```
<a attr="little box" id="test">test<a/>
```

then it work like

```
$('#test').click(function(){  
  alert($(this).attr('little box'));
});
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but how would I get it to loop through the elements on document ready? `.load` doesn't work on divs. :(

Comment: $('element[attr ="little box"]').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
});

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review my question! I appreciate your selflessness. Thank you!